# How we got my previous stackoverflow account

Tags: support, user-accounts

This my second account in stackoverflow, my last account have not permissed to ask any question, I want again I use my last account, without any interruption.

Comment: Why was your account suspended? Did you follow the links in the warning? Did your follow the advice?

Comment: yes i follow all advice , the main reason is asked question quality is not standard , thats reason is closed, but last 2 months i not asked any question and try to gived best answer, i don't knows whats happening in stack community.. i am very disappointment...

Comment: You seem to be giving reasonable answers on SO using this account. Why on earth did you not do that with your previous account? That might have seen the ban lifted already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I went ahead and merged your two accounts. Please do not create new accounts in order to work around the automated question-asking ban.

When you were notified that the older account could no longer post new questions, you were presented with a link to [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-sorry-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers). Read the guidelines there for what triggers this ban and how you can improve your questions to clear this.

In particular, I notice that you deleted 6 of your own questions. This works against you in the question-asking heuristics, as stated on the above-linked page. If you'd like, I could undelete the still open ones for you to improve.

Additionally, we disassociated a disproportionately heavily downvoted question from your account, which might help.

Comment: Thank you Brad Larson .. thnx again::)

Answer (score 13):

You should not start a second account if your first is banned to ask questions.

The right way to solve this problem is to fix the reason why the account was banned. So you can get the right to ask questionbs back.